# How to Launch a Spark Job in EMR creation with terraform

Tags: apache-spark, terraform, amazon-emr

My use case is the following. Via Terraform I want to create an EMR cluster, Start a Spark Job and terminate the cluster when the job is finished.

I found this step mechanism in Terraform documentation (https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/emr_cluster.html#step-1) but I didn't find any example for a Spark Job on Google (an

Maybe i'm doing wrong because my use case seems pretty simple but i can't find an other way to do it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I found it finally 
With step instruction it's possible to launch a Spark Job form a Jar stored in s3

```
step {
    action_on_failure = "TERMINATE_CLUSTER"
    name   = "Launch Spark Job"

    hadoop_jar_step {
      jar  = "command-runner.jar"
      args = ["spark-submit","--class","com.mycompany.App","--master","yarn","s3://my_bucket/my_jar_with_dependencies.jar"]
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, were you able to complete this use case with terraforming? I am also looking for similar stuff.